# Disable past date in jet smart filter date range filter

Tags: wordpress, web, visual-web-developer

I've created a search date range filter using the jet smart filter. All things going well but the issue is that the past date is not disabled as it gets me off. I also use jQuery for it but it does not work for me

Here you can see it still shows all the dates
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc0ZK.png)